# Simple uWSGI won't start with systemd

Tags: debian, uwsgi, systemd

I'm trying to setup uWSGI for development purposed on my desktop, but I can't make it run. I used the example from https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-django but with no luck. The `uwsgi` process starts from command line, but systemd fails to start it.

#### /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/example.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chdir = /var/www
wsgi-file = /var/www/example.wsgi
processes = 4
threads = 2
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

#### /var/www/example.wsgi

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

`sudo uwsgi /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/example.ini` starts the server, but `sudo service uwsgi start` fails. The `journalctl` reports only

```
Aug 31 11:22:36 queeg-500 uwsgi[18918]: Starting app server(s): uwsgi -> ! failed!
Aug 31 11:22:36 queeg-500 systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 31 11:22:36 queeg-500 systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 31 11:22:36 queeg-500 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s).
```

I couldn't found any useful log whatsoever. I'm running on Debian testing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I actually solved it by using uwsgi in an emperor mode, specifically by uwsgi-emperor package instead of uwsgi.